# Timer for sending request at some time period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have specific trouble: I'm using Yandex.Disk cloud storage and working with this by Yandex.Disk REST API. I have some functionality for syncing data and saving to db. Specially it's file name, file md5, file download url. But trouble is that download url is temporary. And I'm looking for solution, to have ability for apdating download url for all saved in db files, each 24 hours. First solution I found is another project that will be launching by windows task scheduler, but my hosting provider not giving this ability. Help me please to find good solution for this.

Comment: You must put a code here, not just "how I can make it"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use hangfire http://hangfire.io/ to create a recurring task within your ASP.NET application.